# Is there a preferred way to serialize external objects to json format in python

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am using a Client API to get data and when I use `json.loads(api_response.results)` it is showing `TypeError('Object of type ExternalUnifiedEvent is not JSON serializable);`
So instead of using `json.loads()` I am deconstructing the data like below so that I can able to use `json.dumps()` later to send this data in a post request. Is this the best way to do this as `ExternalUnifiedEvent` type doesn't exist in my code base?

```
def get_data():

   try:
       api_response = client_api.get()
       data = []
       for i in api_reponse.results:
           e = {
               "event_id": i.event_id
               "event_type": i.event_type
               "properties": i.properties
            }
           data.append(e)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",}

payload = get_data()

response = requests.post(webhook_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: What type of object is *api_response* ?

Comment: It's a custom class object from the API endpoint `events.models.collection_response_external_unified_event.CollectionResponseExternalUnifiedEvent`

Comment: Please update your post and include your custom class object.